# Multi inheritance with template interface

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance

Consider following piece of code:

template.h

```
template<typename T>
class templ{
public:
    virtual const int virtualMethod(const T *const) const = 0;
}
```

Base.h

```
#include "template.h"

class Der1;
class Der2;

    class Base :
        public templ<Base>,
        public templ<Der1>,
        public templ<Der2>{
    public:
        virtual ~Base(){}
    };
```

Der1.h

```
#include "Base.h"

class Der1 : public Base {
public:
    virtual const int virtualMethod(const Base *const) const override;
    virtual const int virtualMethod(const Der1 *const) const override;
    virtual const int virtualMethod(const Der2 *const) const override;
};
```

Der1.cpp

```
#include "Der1.h"

const int Der1::virtualMethod(const Base *const sth) const{
    return sth->templ<Der1>::virtualMethod(this);//does not work
    //how to fix it?
}

const int Der1::virtualMethod(const Der1 *const sth) const{
    //do sth
}

const int Der1::virtualMethod(const Der2 *const sth) const{
    //do sth
}
```

Class Der2 also inherits from Base and implements these three functions.

For this code compiler gives me these messages:

1. 'templ' is ambiguous ' Candidates are: templ() templ(const
   templ &) templ() templ(const templ &) templ()
   templ(const templ &) '
2. Function 'virtualMethod' could not be resolved
3. Namespace member function 'virtualMethod' cannot be resolved.
4. Type 'Der1' cannot be resolved.
5. undefined reference to
   `templ::virtualMethod(Der1 const*) const'

In general, the idea of the code was to implement double type dispatch. Although I think I know what causes problems, I have no idea how to solve it. So maybe you can help me.

Comment: You probably want to use a [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) rather than an embedded abstract base class.

Comment: Please do not mix static polymorphism (templates) and dynamic polymorphism (virtual), unless you know what you a doing.

Comment: Also, when defining  interfaces, you should use virtual inheritance (avoid multiple base classes)

Comment: Can you post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Your code compiles fine as-is, unless you're missing includes or something.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused what was your intention...

But what about:

```
const int Der1::virtualMethod(const Base *sth) const { 
     return dynamic_cast<const templ<Der1> *>(sth)->virtualMethod(this);
}
```

Comment: This is definitely **NOT** what I looked for. The main purpose of code written by me is avoiding dynamic_cast and RTTI. No to mention Your code is dangerous due to not checking dynamic cast result for `nullptr`.

Comment: Of course, you should checking cast result but I ignore that because it wasn't the majority of solution and I think in this situation it is not required because cast always will be positive (unless sth = nullptr, it is not checked in your code too).